# Using an intent to send data of an item from Firestore UI RecyclerView to next activity

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I have implemented a RecyclerView using the Firestore UI. It displays currently a username and a profile picture. When the user clicks on any item of the RecyclerView he gets to a user profile activity. There, the name and the profile picture of the user should be displayed which is currently not the case because I don't know how to send the data of one item to the next activity and set the TextView to its value. Is an intent the best approach or should I just sent the UID of the user that got clicked and then retrieve the data of the user from Firestore within the "User Profile Activity"? How can I achieve this? There are tutorials on how to achieve this with the Real Time Database but I don't want to switch the database.

Here is my activity where the RecyclerView is implemented:

```
...
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_search);
...
        userAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new UserAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

                String user_id = documentSnapshot.getId();
            }
        });
...
```

Here is the Adapter class of the RecyclerView with an intent that opens the next activity:

```
public class UserAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Users, UserAdapter.UserHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public UserAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Users> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Users model) {

        holder.textViewUsername.setText(model.getUsername());

        Picasso.get()
                .load(model.getAvatar_id())
                .into(holder.circleImageView);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem_search_result,parent, false);
        return new UserHolder(view);
    }

    class UserHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewUsername;
        CircleImageView circleImageView;

        public UserHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_name_search);
            circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_avatar_player_search);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null){
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position),(position));
                        Intent i = new Intent (itemView.getContext(), FriendRequest.class);
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(i);
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

The structure of my Collection is this:

```
User
    uid
        username: "Player1"
        avatar_id: "uri of a picture stored in Storage"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you trying passing the whole _Users_ object using Intent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to send the information from one activity to other use the Intent

```
Intent i = new Intent (itemView.getContext(), FriendRequest.class);
i.putExtra("username", textViewUsername.getText().toString());
i.putExtra("profile",model.getAvatar_id());
itemView.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

and in yours FriendRequest activity, use getIntent to receive that data.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");
String link = intent.getExtra("profile");
```

now you can use these values.

Comment: This worked for the username but not for the avatar_id. The "model" in ```model.getAvatar_id```has an error (Cannot resolve symbol)